# What does twiddle $\tilde x$ (roughly $x$ with ~ above it) mean in this expression?

Tags: calculus, notation

What does the $\tilde x$ ($x$ with ~ above) mean in these expressions?

[image: Screen grab]

Comment: [It's called a tilde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).

Comment: Where did you come across this? BTW, to typeset $\tilde{x}$, write `$\tilde{x}$`.

Comment: Maybe is only a different variable... maybe you have to read your textbook.

Comment: Where is the table from? This might refer to some very specific application meaning in optics for example

Comment: This is about typesetting. It shows how large spaces are used in (LaTeX) documents to type cos(<formula>)

Comment: $\tilde x$ is a notaton that can come up for virtually any reason. Sometimes is just another variable, sometimes is a thing that depends on $x$. You'll have to read the definitions that the book gives.

Comment: Meaning of tilde depend on context. Usually $\tilde{x}$ is some variable related to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

My question arose from viewing [this](https://www.scribd.com/document/84379172/Cosine-Spacing) where I can only see the first couple of pages.

I eventually tracked down a site that allowed me to see page 53, where it reads:[image]